# How to show that the function: $ f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}^3, x \mapsto (\sin(x),\cos(x),x^2 )$ is injective?

Tags: analysis, functions

How to show that the function: $ f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}^3, x \mapsto (\sin(x),\cos(x),x^2 )$ is injective?

---

To prove this, I was thinking to start by supposing that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$; this implies that $(\sin(x_1),\cos(x_1),x_1^2 ) = (\sin(x_2),\cos(x_2),x_2^2)$. This gives us $\sin(x_1)=\sin(x_2) \Longleftrightarrow  x_1=x_2$,
$ \cos(x_1)=\cos(x_2) \Longleftrightarrow x_1=x_2 $ and
$ x_1^2=x_2^2 \Longleftrightarrow x_1=x_2$.

Is this correct? Should I add something to this proof? If yes, what?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{I}$ in this case?

Comment: It is the interval (0,1)

Comment: Do you know which step(s) in your argument holds when the domain is $(0,1)$ and doesn't hold when the domain is $\mathbb{R}$?  If so, you should add a justification to that step.  (It currently looks less like a proof and more like a claim)

Comment: I would suggest examining the two possible cases $x_1 = \pm x_2$ that arise from $x_1^2=x_2^2$ with the goal of concluding $x_1 = x_2$.

Comment: It is sufficient to note that the map $t \mapsto (\cos t, \sin t)$  is injective on $[0,2 \pi)$.

Comment: Note that $x\mapsto x^2$ is injective for $x\in(0,1)$; the first two coordinates are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you concluded too quickly. The first two equations, namely $\sin x_1 = \sin x_2$ and $\cos x_1 = \cos x_2$ don't imply $x_1 = x_2$ but $x_1 = x_2 + 2\pi k$, $k \in \Bbb{Z}$, because of the $2\pi$-periodicity of the sine and cosine functions. Then, the third equation imposes $$x_1^2 = x_2^2 = (x_1 + 2\pi k)^2 = x_1^2 + 2\pi kx_1 + 4\pi^2k^2,$$ hence $2\pi k(x_1 + 2\pi k) = 0$, which itself implies $k = 0$ and thus $x_1 = x_2$. Note that the solution $x_1 = -2\pi k$ has to be discarded, because it wouldn't belong to $\Bbb{I}$.

Comment: I want to note that even if there were a nonzero integer $k$ such that $x_1 = -2 \pi k \in \mathbb{I}$, we can see from $x_1^2=x_2^2=(x_1+2 \pi k)^2$ that $x_1 = -2 \pi k \implies x_1 = x_2 = 0 \implies k=0$.